# Constructing a particular Toeplitz matrix with a certain rule

Tags: matrix

I want to construct a Toeplitz matrix in *Mathematica*. Usually it is done in *Mathematica* using the following command:

```
ToeplitzMatrix[{a,b,...},{a,y,...}]
```

I want to have the first and the second list like `{a,b,...}` and `{a,y,...}` above to each contain `N` elements for a given number `N` (say 5 or 6; I want to keep the option of changing it). I want `a=0`. From `b` onwards I want to have `(-1)^n nx` (starting with `n=1`) and from `y` onwards `-(-1)^n nx`  alternatively.

So at the end, it should look like 
\begin{pmatrix}
0\quad x\quad -2x\quad\dots\\
-x\quad 0\quad x\quad \dots\\
2x\quad -x\quad 0\quad \dots\\
\dots
\end{pmatrix}

I am quite new to all the powers of *Mathematica*. So some help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
tf[nn_] := With[{n = Range[0, nn]}, ToeplitzMatrix[(-1)^n n x, -(-1)^n n x]]
```

For the question in the comment:

```
tf2[nn_] := 
 With[{n = Range[0, nn]}, 
  Module[{expr = (-1)^n Cot@(n x)}, expr[[1]] = 0; ToeplitzMatrix[expr, -expr]]]

tf3[nn_] := 
 With[{n = Range@nn}, 
  With[{expr = Join[{0}, (-1)^n Cot@(n x)]}, ToeplitzMatrix[expr, -expr]]]
```

Comment: Sorry, but it says:

Comment: "Objects of unequal length in {1,-1,1,-1,1}\ {0,1,2,3,4}\ {\[Pi]/12,\
\[Pi]/6,\[Pi]/4,\[Pi]/3,(5\\[Pi])/12,\[Pi]/2,(7\\[Pi])/12,(2\\[Pi])/3,\
(3\\[Pi])/4,(5\\[Pi])/6,(11\\[Pi])/12,\[Pi],(13\\[Pi])/12,(7\\[Pi])/6,\
(5\\[Pi])/4,(4\\[Pi])/3,(17\\[Pi])/12,(3\\[Pi])/2,(19\\[Pi])/12,(5\\[\
Pi])/3,(7\\[Pi])/4,(11\\[Pi])/6,(23\\[Pi])/12,2\ \[Pi]} cannot be \
combined"

Comment: Also, here the first element 0 is obtained just by putting 0 for n in (-1)^n nx. But what if I have 0 for the diagonals and say (-1)^n cot(nx), so that I really need to put a second rule for the diagonals?

Comment: @Student You forgot to `Clear[x]`

Comment: Sorry, it is working for what you said. But for the other one I mentioned, I can't do e.g. tf[nn_] := With[{n = Range[0, nn]}, ToeplitzMatrix[{0,(-1)^n Cot[n x]}, {0,-(-1)^n Cot[n x]}]].

Comment: @Student See my edit

Comment: Yes, it's working of course. Thanks so much! I am now solving a chain of problems in mathematica, so I probably need to keep visiting this site.